# How to make make concurrent calls on each object of a list?

Tags: java, list, concurrency

I have a list that contains 3 objects and I want to call a method on each object concurrently

Normally I would loop through each object in my list and call the method on each object.

```
for(Object object : myList){
     object.someMethod();
}
```

This will call `someMethod()` on each object from `myList` one by one.
Can I call `someMethod()` on each object at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can call someMethod in parallel in multiple ways

**Using Parallel Stream**

```
 myList.parallelStream().forEach(object -> object. someMethod())
```

**Using Executor Service**

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(myList.size());
 for(Object object : myList){
      executorService.submit(object::someMethod)
 }
  executorService.shutdown();
```